# Apple iOS Tutorial: Problems getting UIButton addTarget to Work

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift3

I am working through the "Start Developing iOS Apps" tutorial provided by Apple, and having a problem in the [Implement a Custom Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) section. I have tried everything to get the button to print something to the console, but can't get it to work. I am on the section in the tutorial "Add Buttons to the View" about a fifth of the way down the page.

Everything else works fine.

I have set up the RatingControl.swift file as follows:

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {

    // MARK: Initialisation
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Create a square button
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))

        // Set the background colour of the button
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown)

        // Add the button to the view
        addSubview(button)
    }

    // MARK: Button Action
    func ratingButtonTapped(_: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed")
    }
}
```

A few things there are slightly different to the tutorial, but that is because Xcode says things have changed.
In my Main.storyboard file I have added a View using the RatingControl class. The button displays but nothing happens when I click it.

Any help would be appreciated. If any extra information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Give the View in the storyboard that uses the RatingControl class a background color, so that you can see whether the button is completely inside the view. It needs to be, or it won't respond when tapped. Also, make sure you have check User Interaction Enabled for the rating control, for the same reason. — Also, are you sure you want to use `.touchDown`? The usual thing is `.touchUpInside`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried making that happen by adding "self.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan" just after "super.init(coder: aDecoder)" but it didn't change the background colour of the view. I also tried changing the background colour of the view in the storyboard attributes inspector for the view. Neither caused a change to the background colour. What am I missing? I did notice "User Interaction Enabled" before and it is checked. I was only using .touchDown because the tutorial said to use that. I did wonder. Changed it to .touchUpInside but it didn't make the button work.

Comment: I moved the view out of a stack it was in, to just below, and everything works. The background colour set in the storyboard works and the button does what it should. As soon as I move it back in to the stack, it stops working. User interaction is enabled on the stack view and the control just above it in the stack works fine. Don't understand it.

Comment: It's what I already told you. You know how you didn't see the view ("it didn't change the background colour of the view")? Well, that is because being in the stack view caused the rating control view to become zero sized. And so the button, a subview of a zero-sized view, became untappable.

Comment: Thanks. So why does it work when it's outside the stack view? If it was the size being zero wouldn't that cause the same problem whether or not in a stack view? It does have a size set on it. In size inspector it has intrinsic size set to placeholder, width 240, height 44. Or is there something I need to do to stop the stack view making it zero sized?

Comment: There was nothing about the stack view in your original question. Now you are asking a whole new question about the behavior of custom views when placed in a stack view. That's a good question, but it is not what you asked about. I've explained the phenomena completely, I believe. Adding the background color proves I'm right: your button was a subview of a zero-sized view (proved because the superview's background color was not present), and hence untappable.

Comment: Well it doesn't explain it, because as I say, the view that it is a sub-view of is not zero sized and never has been. So there is no zero size issue here unless you can point out to me where there is one I'm unaware of, which is what the questions in previous comment were driving at. I can add info about the storyboard to my question if that helps. I didn't add it because it didn't seem relevant. I did say in the question if any extra information is needed let me know. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: "the view that it is a sub-view of is not zero sized" Yes it is. You said yourself that in the stack view the cyan background color failed to appear around the button. That is because the superview of the button had been sized to zero. And that, as I have told you many times now, made the button untappable.

Comment: Thanks. It's not that. The stack view/superview is sized using constraints. For a test, I put an intrinsic size of placeholder on it, bigger than needed, and it made no difference. Thanks for your help. I'm learning a lot even if not figured out this problem yet. There must be something else causing the cyan not to show up? I understand that would make the button untappable, but it does not seem to be what is happening here. It looks like there must be another explanation.

Comment: No, the stack view is fine. It is the cyan view that is the problem. It is what gets sized down to zero by being in the stack view. You can readily prove this by using the View Debugger and examining the size of the (invisible) cyan view. Another way to prove it: set the cyan view's `clipsToBounds` to `true`. This will cause the button, too, to go missing! That's because the button, as I've said, is outside the cyan view's bounds (when the cyan view is in the stack view).

Comment: Got it, thanks. The auto layout guide is on my reading list so hopefully that will help me understand why. If not I'll ask another question soon. It's poor that the Apple official intro to developing iOS apps has this problem with its lesson, since I've followed it all exactly.

Comment: Okay. I'll add what we learned as an answer!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look out for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a hierarchy of three views in this story:

- A stack view (not mentioned in the original question)

  - The RatingControl

    - The button

Well, the stack view, a complicated control whose job involves a lot of voodoo with the constraints of its arranged subviews, is reducing the size of the RatingControl to zero. The button is thus outside the RatingControl's bounds (easily proved by giving the RatingControl a background color — the background color doesn't appear). The RatingControl does not clip to its bounds, so the button is still *visible* — but, being outside its superview, it is not *tappable*.

As for *why* the stack view is reducing the size of the RatingControl to zero: it's because the RatingControl has no `intrisicContentSize`. The reason why we need this is complicated and has to do with how a stack view manipulates its arranged subviews and gives them constraints. But in essence, it makes a lot of its decisions based on an arranged view's `intrinsicContentSize`.

In the comments you said:

> In size inspector it has intrinsic size set to placeholder, width 240, height 44. Or is there something I need to do to stop the stack view making it zero sized?

The key thing to understand here is that that setting in the size inspector is *only* a placeholder. It is merely to shut the storyboard up so that it won't complain. It doesn't actually give the view any intrinsic size at runtime. To do that, you must actually override the [`intrinsicContentSize` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize), *in your code*, as a computed variable returning an actual size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This states the problem accurately, but how can it be fixed?

Comment: Oh, as to that, I would need to know much more about how the stack view and the RatingControl view are configured (and what else, if anything, is in the stack view and how _that_ is configured). You could ask a whole new question giving that info. I believe I've answered _this_ question, which is why the button couldn't be tapped.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't mark the answer accepted when it doesn't fix the problem. I've marked it up though, since it's certainly helped identify the problem. The question can be updated with the information you need, as offered in the question, if you would like to look at it. Otherwise I'm going to leave this unresolved for now and perhaps provide my own answer once I learn more about stack views.

Comment: That's fine, of course! The good news is that now you're on the right road: you know what to investigate and why.

Comment: Okay, in our comment conversation it turns out you let slip a remark that tells me what the underlying problem is. So I'm editing my answer to add that.

Comment: Thanks matt, that's great. I understand what's going on now and have fixed it in my code. All working perfectly. It is actually mentioned in the tutorial, but as overriding a function, not a property, which obviously got rejected by Xcode, and then when the full code is shown further down the tutorial it's not included, so I left it out thinking it wasn't needed. Great to have your help and advice. Thanks for coming back to this and good to have it resolved.

Comment: Right, you're using an old tutorial. Back in those days, `intrinsicContentSize` was a method, not property. But you still can't afford to omit it entirely! (That sounds like a bug in the tutorial.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're stumbling through the "Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)" tutorial before it's updated for iOS 10 and Swift 3. Amazing you've made it this far! Anyhow, @matt has a great technical explanation below but did not include the actual code to get your tutorial working:

Add the following to your class definition (outside the init function):

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Regarding the tutorial... thanks, yes, well I read the whole Swift 3 Language Guide from Apple before doing it, and Xcode has been very good at pointing out changes too. The challenges have helped me learn a lot. But really it's poor that Apple have not updated this yet, especially since they make such a big thing of it being easy to learn to build iOS apps.

Comment: Suuuper late to the party, but u mentioned "(...) tutorial before it's updated". I just stumbled upon the same bug. Is there a newer tutorial anywhere to be found? Since this question was answered..4 years ago. 
I just can't find any newer tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

then your code will work : -

```
   class RatingView: UIView {

    // MARK: Initialisation
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Create a square button
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 100, width: 44, height: 44))

        // Set the background colour of the button
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown)

        // Add the button to the view
        addSubview(button)
    }

    // MARK: Button Action
    func ratingButtonTapped(_: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed")
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I tried this but it complains that "Value of type 'RatingControl' has no member 'view'" But anyway the button is showing up, just not working interactively, so it seems that line is working fine as it is.

Comment: Thanks. But it looks like actually there's nothing wrong with the code, it's an issue (so far unidentified) with the stack view used as the superview. See comments on the question and the provided answer.

Comment: The issue has now been fully identified and resolved. See the accepted answer. Thanks.